# the use of an 'if' inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working through [Norvig's BASIC interpreter implemented in Python](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/ipynb/BASIC.ipynb).

There's a bit of code that seems extraneous to me, but this guy seems 100 levels beyond me, so it's more likely that I fail to understand rather than he wrote something unnecessary.

```
def lines(text): 
    "A list of the non-empty lines in a text."
    return [line for line in text.splitlines() if line]
    #return [zaa for zaa in text.splitlines()]
```

The list comprehension -- why does it finish with `if line`?

If I remove that clause, using  `[zaa for zaa in text.splitlines()]` instead, I still the think the function works if I pass it text or even a blank line.

```
foo ="""mike\nnew\nbar"""
bar ="\n\n"
print lines(foo)
print lines(bar)
what = lines(bar)
print(type(what))

['mike', 'new', 'bar']
[]
<type 'list'>
```

I must be misundersatnding something -- I cannot understand when that `if line` is even evaluated,  let alone its necessity in processing the inputs properly.

Edit: found the example where the lack of the `if line` will give bad results:

```
bar ="""one
two
three

five

seven"""
#bar = ""
print lines(bar)

['one', 'two', 'three', '', 'five', '', 'seven']
```

It includes those two empty strings as members of the list.

Comment: To filter out non empty elements.

Comment: Only elements that satisfy the if are put into the list. This should be covered in any comprehension tutorial.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think they are confused because the `if line` doesn't appear to have an actual condition. The source of this confusion is `truthy` values. OP I suggest you read this: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html it's short and easy to understand and `truthy` values can be very convenient

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Mm, that should be made clearer if that's the case. That kind of changes the entire question. I suspect though that regardless of which it is, there's a dupe available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if line` is checking for "truthy" values, which are characters that are determined `False` or `True` when checked. For instance, an empty string `''` is considered `False`, along with empty lists (`[]`), dictionaries (`{}`), tuples (`()`), `0`, and `None`. Essentially, `if line` is a shorter version of:

```
return [line for line in text.splitlines() if line != '']
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: it **filters out empty strings** out of the result.

In Python list comprehension has the form:

```
[<expr> for <vars> in <iterable> <filters-and-iterators>]
```

where `<filters-and-iterators>` are sequence of:

1. iterators of the form `for <vars> in <iterable>`; and
2. **filters** of the form **`if <expr>`**.

Python will evaluate the ***truthiness*** of the . Only in case the expression has *truthiness* `True`, it will pass that element: if the filter is the last step, this means adding it to the list; if the filter is not the last step, process further (for instance processing the next iterator or filter). Otherwise it will ignore that item.

A **`str`ing** has *truthiness* `True` if and only if **the string contains at least one character**. So that means here we filter out non-empty strings.

The truthiness of a custom class can be implemented by overriding the `__bool__` magic function, or in case it is missing, Python will look if the `__len__` returns a non-zero value.

`None` and `False` have always truthiness `False`, `True` has truthiness `True`, collections like lists, sets, dictionaries, tuples and strings have truthiness `True` if and only if these contain at least one element. Numerical values usually have truthiness `True` if these are non-zero (so negative numbers have truthiness `True` as well).

A programmer is free to implement truthiness for a custom class itself (as described above), although it is usually a good idea to take the examples here into account and thus think about non-emptiness as truthiness for collections.